# How to preload audio files in angular project?

Tags: angular, audio, audio-player

I have made a project in angular. I want to play small mp3 file on button click event that when user click on various buttons from UI, music should be played based on selected button. I want to preload all the music files which is in mp3 format that my UI should be visible to screen only after mp3 files are loaded in angular. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular Router provides a resolve property that takes a route resolver and allows your application to fetch data before navigating to the route (i.e resolving route data).
You can create a route resolver by implementing the Resolve interface.
For example:

audio-resolver.service.ts:

```cpp
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
       
  @Injectable()
  export class AudioResolver implements Resolve<Promise<string[]>>{
  
    audioFiles = [
      "http://www.teanglann.ie/CanC/nua.mp3",
      "http://www.teanglann.ie/CanC/ag.mp3",
      "http://www.teanglann.ie/CanC/dul.mp3",
      "http://www.teanglann.ie/CanC/freisin.mp3"
    ];
  
    resolve = (): Promise<string[]> => Promise.all(this.audioFiles.map(this.preloadAudio))
  
    preloadAudio = (url: string): Promise<string> => {
      const audio = new Audio();
      audio.src = url;
      return new Promise((res, req) => audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => res(url), false))
      // once file is loaded, the promise will be resolved
      // the file will be kept by the browser as cache
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the only requirement to implement the Angular router’s Resolve interface is that our class has a resolve method. Whatever is returned from that method will be the resolved data, in our case the returned value is `Promise<string[]>` which will be resolved to the urls-array.

Now you can setup our routing module to include our resolver:

app.routing.module.ts:

```cpp
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
  import { PlayerComponent } from './components/player/player.component';
  import { AudioResolver} from './services/audio-resolver.service';
        
  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: PlayerComponent, resolve: { songs: ResolverService } }
  ];
  
  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [AudioResolver]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In the component, we can access the resolved data using the data property of ActivatedRoute’s snapshot object.

player.component.ts:

```cpp
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
  
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-player',
    templateUrl: './player.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./player.component.scss']
  })
  export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
    songs: string[];
  
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  
    ngOnInit() {
        this.songs = this.route.snapshot.data.songs;
    }
  }
```

player.component.html:

```html
<audio *ngFor="let src of songs" [src]="src" controls="" ><br></audio>
```

Now if you go ahead and look at the browser network, you would see that the files are being loaded before the `PlayerComponent` has been initialized, and never being loaded again.